# Subtle distinction between "at once" and "all at once"?

Tags: differences, idioms, word-usage

According to [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/once_1#once_1) both "*all at once*" and "*at once*" can mean *at the same time*.

> I can't do everything all at once
>
> I can't do two things at once.
>
> Don't all speak at once!

These examples give me the idea that "*at once*" could be used when referring to a countable thing (in the latter example *all* is countable because it refers to a specific count of people, e.g. a class) while "*all at once*" is taken when referring to a non-countable thing (of course, *everything* could possibly be a countable thing).

Are they always used interchangeably or is one preferred in certain contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different idioms here, and you may be confused. In *Don't all speak at once*, *all* and *at once* are separate, and both modify *speak*; the normal rules apply to *all/both*, as Barrie has said. But *all at once* can also be a single phrase, where *all* intensifies *at once* ("When all at once my heart took flight", *My Fair Lady*).  I don't believe there are any rules for when you can or can't use that.

Answer (score 3):

My intuition is to say that you don't need *all* when you're talking about only two things. The number isn't large enough to justify its use.